# What's the difference between these two simple SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Emp(eid: integer, ename: string, age: integer, salary: real)

Works(eid: integer, did: integer, pct time: integer)

Dept(did: integer, dname: string, budget: real, managerid: integer)
SELECT DISTINCT D.managerid

FROM Dept D

WHERE 1000000 < ALL (SELECT D2.budget
 FROM Dept D2
 WHERE D2.managerid = D.managerid )


other one:
SELECT DISTINCT managerid FROM dept WHERE dept.budget > 1000000
```

They both get the id of managers who work in departments with budgets higher than 1million. Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: One of them unneccessarily uses a subquery, which may cause performance to suffer.  They are semantically the same.

Comment: Look at the execution plan for each query. How to do so depends on the specific RDBMS you're using, which you didn't indicate (despite it having been suggested when you added the SQL tag).

Comment: @KenWhite, what do you mean by execution plan?

Comment: The `ALL` operator makes the difference. It is not often used, so the commenters above may not give you the right answer. The answer below is applicable to any RDBMS.

Comment: I mean the *plan of execution as determined by the server*. Again, you've *still* not included a tag that mentions the specific RDBMS you're using, so I can't provide any more information than that; you should [edit] your post to add that tag.

Comment: @KenWhite I insist that it does not depend on the RDBMS. The ALL operator is a standard SQL operator that must be supported by any RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is with the `ALL` operator. Read [here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_all.php) about the ALL operator when it is used with the comparison operators.

The difference will be for the cases where a manager oversees multiple departments.

If you have a manager that looks after these two departments:

```
declare @Dept table (did integer, dname varchar(20), budget real, managerid integer)
insert into @Dept values(1, 'dept1', 10, 1),(2, 'dept2', 20000000, 1)
```

Then the first query will not give you any results, as the manager with the managerid=1 has a department with budget over and less then 1000000

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.managerid
FROM @Dept D
WHERE 1000000 < ALL (SELECT D2.budget
 FROM @Dept D2
 WHERE D2.managerid = D.managerid )

managerid
-----------
(0 row(s) affected)
```

The second query happily returns the result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT managerid FROM @dept WHERE budget > 1000000

managerid
-----------
1
(1 row(s) affected)
```

**UPDATE:** to make the two queries equivalent you can use the `ANY` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.managerid
FROM @Dept D
WHERE 1000000 < ANY (SELECT D2.budget
 FROM @Dept D2
 WHERE D2.managerid = D.managerid )
managerid
-----------
1
(1 row(s) affected)
```

I have added the picture from the URL above here, for completeness:

[image: ALL operator in pictures]